# SetTimeout lags between calls in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, firefox, css-animations

I'm trying to optimize my code so that I can cycle through images on a splash page quickly and effectively. I've got it looking really smooth on chrome and safari but when I view the splash page on mobile and firefox it bugs out big time

A demo can be found at http://theotherchrisrock.com

I would love to hear your input on how to fix this. Here is the relevant code:

```
var i = 0
var j = 0
var l = $('.se-pre-con > div').length - 2;
var $pre_con = $('.se-pre-con');
var $di_sum = $('.splash-image:last-child');
var $img_array = [];
for (t = 0; t < l; t++) {
  $img_array[t] = $('.splash-image-' + t);
}

function flashanimation() {

  if (i < l) {
    $img_array[i].addClass('flash');
    i++;
    flashloop();
  } else if (j != 1) {
    $di_sum.addClass('di-some');
    j = 1
    flashloop();
  } else {
    $pre_con.addClass('nun');
  }
}

function flashloop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    flashanimation();
  }, 300)
}

$(".blinker").removeClass("blinker");
flashloop();
```

Basically, the goal is to make the image appear for 150ms and then disappear for 150ms and then next image appears and so on finally ending with just a black div. Right now I'm adding a class to each div which triggers this keyframe animation ~

```
.splash-image.flash {
    -webkit-animation:flash 0.15s linear;
            animation:flash 0.15s linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.15s;
            animation-delay:0.15s;
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    1% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    1% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

I would love to hear your input. Thank u for reviewing my question

Comment: I just loaded the website on Laptop: Chrome, Laptop: Firefox, and iPhone: Safari, and I didn't notice any delay. Although the pictures *were moving very fast* so I may not have noticed the difference. **Try using another set of devices and different internet connections?**

Comment: I don't see much difference in FF and Chrome. I do notice a little difference the first time I open the page versus refreshing, I assume that's because the images are cached.

Comment: Yeah i Have it set up right now so that the animation only starts once the assets have been downloaded so it shouldnt affect its performance. I'm stumped I guess on the one hand I'm relieved that this isn't persisting on your firefox browser but I'm struggling when I consider what to do about the performance on mine. Thank u for taking a look. I'm not used to getting a second pair of eyes on my code so I appreciate any feedback I can get